# Product of ground eigen-energy with highest eigen-energy of 3 qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Consider a 3-qubit quantum system with ground state $|\psi_0\rangle$ and highest energy state (for the problem at hand, in general there might be higher) $|\psi_{\rm top}\rangle$. The corresponding eigen-energies are $E_0$ and $E_{\rm top}$.

Given that these are eigenstates of the 3-local Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H} = \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{1} - \mathbb{1}\otimes \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y - \sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \sigma_x
$$
**what is the product $E_0 E_{\rm top}$?**

---

**Ideas**:
I am not so sure how to compute this. I can write $|\psi_0\rangle$ as follows:
$$
|\psi_0\rangle = a|000\rangle + b|010\rangle + c|100\rangle + d|110\rangle + e|001\rangle + f|011\rangle + g|101\rangle + h|111\rangle.
$$
Then I can apply the Hamiltonian $\hat H$ and transform the kets. What guarantees that in the end I will get an eigen-energy? If I do, so if in the end I fing $\hat{H}|\psi_0\rangle= c|\psi_0\rangle$ then $c=E_0$.

But how will I approach the same thing for the unknown $|\psi_{\rm top}\rangle$?

Also, does this problem have some sort of a name?

---

After the answers given below:

$$
\hat{H} = \begin{pmatrix}
     1   &  0 &    0  &   1  &   0   & -1  &   0  &   0 \\
     0    & 1  &  -1   &  0  &  -1    & 0   &  0    & 0 \\
     0   & -1  &  -1    & 0  &   0   &  0 &    0    -1 \\
     1    & 0  &   0    &-1   &  0  &   0  &  -1  &   0 \\
     0  &  -1    & 0   &  0  &  -1   &  0  &   0  &   1 \\
    -1   &  0   &  0  &   0   &  0 &   -1    &-1  &   0 \\
     0 &    0   &  0    &-1  &   0  &  -1   &  1  &   0 \\
     0   &  0  &  -1   &  0  &   1   &  0  &   0  &   1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and one can plug this into Matlab or such to find the two eigenvalues.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you exactly are asking for? *what is the product $E_0E_{\mathrm{top}}$?* does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Yes, to find a formula or an estimate on what $E_0E_{\rm top}$ is. Or, more generally, how I would estimate $E_{\rm top}$.

Comment: Okay, so your question is how to find an (presumably) approximation of the product $E_0 \, E_{\mathrm{top}}$, where $E_0$ is the ground state energy and $E_{\mathrm{top}}$ the highest energy eigenvalue? If so, it could make sense to edit the question and not simply ask *what is ...* - because it is a product of two real numbers and in principle you can obtain each number by diagonalizing $H$ (i.e. find its eigenvalues) and then multiplying them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got it now. I thought the question was tricky, this is why I got confused. I edited the question with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the energy eigenvalues. Write $H$ as a $2^3$ by $2^3$ matrix and compute its eigenvalues (some of them will be degenerate). Take the highest and the lowest and multiply them together.

Comment: Why $2^3 \times 2^3$? If the Hamiltonian was only the first term, for example, then would it not be $H = {\rm BlockDiag}(\sigma_z,\sigma_z,1)$?

Comment: That is not how tensor products work. The matrix you wrote is 6x6, but you have 8 basis vectors in $\mathbb C^2 \otimes \mathbb C^2 \otimes \mathbb C^2$, as you write correctly in your second formula.

Comment: Indeed, I get two degenerate eigenvalues.

Comment: Problem solved then! I bet there is a more clever way to go about it, but if you have access to mathematica this brute force approach works very well.

Comment: I am puzzled as to why anybody is interested in this product. Thanks, I should had thought about it myself.

Comment: At second order perturbation theory you get expressions of the form $(E_n-E_0)^2$... but yes, probably they are just testing you can compute eigenvalues.